# Stuck with Sequelize create

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js

I have an issue while trying to add new records into my database.

So I have this code:

```
const schema = require('./Labels.schema');

const Labels = sequelize.define('labels', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    field: 'id'
  },
  user: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    field: 'user'
  },
  code: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    field: 'code'
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    field: 'name'
  }
},
  {
    tableName: 'labels'
    timestamps: false
  });

Labels.createLabel = async (params) => {
  sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    });
  params.user = process.env.USER_ID;
  const res = joi.validate(params, schema.create);
  if(!res) {
    Labels.create(params).then(data => {
      console.log('test log');
    });
  } else {
    throw new Error(res);
  }
};
```

This is just a basic model of the record that needs to be stored.
I have tried some varients with the create function, sync, async, within try catch. But I just can't get any output what-so-ever. Even if I do a `console.log` after the create, it doesn't log. So it seems like it gets blocked somehow. That's why I put the `sequelize.authenticate` to test the connection, but even that doesn't give me any result.

I fairly new to Sequelize, so any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Stablish the connection before hand. Also, you are not returning anything from that function

Comment: You have an `async function` there, but you never `await` the promises within it?

Comment: @Bergi I've tried multiple varients of the create. Also the `await`. I should have made that clear aswell.

Comment: @yBrodsky I require the sequelize instance of the connection in the top. Eventhough it is not stated in my question, it is there. If I log that instance it give me, what seems to be, the correct sequelize object, containing the database connection values